# How do I know, how long Aurora Auto-Scaling instances had been run for a specific time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling, amazon-aurora

I've Aurora Cluster that have auto-scaling policies. And I want to know how many hours my auto-scaling instance running for a month. What metrics in cloudwatch can do that?

I'am expecting a how many total hours spend by auto-scalling instances in a month.
If 2 auto-scalling instances fully run in a month than the value should be 30 day * 24 hours * 2 auto-scaling instances = 1440 hours.